# How to use Sitecore Express Migration Tool introduced in Sitecore 8.2?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore7.2, sitecore8.2

I want to know the steps taken to migrate Sitecore 7.2 to Sitecore 8.2 using the Express migration tool.
Does the Sitecore Express Migration Tool helps in migration to all the later versions also?

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation? https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Express_Migration_Tool/10/Express_Migration_Tool_10_Initial_Release.aspx

Comment: Thanks @RichardSeal, the doc was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Per the documentation, it only helps to migrate any version of Sitecore 7.2.

[image]

You need to download the zip file from https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Express_Migration_Tool/10/Express_Migration_Tool_10_Initial_Release.aspx and fill the required information: Website folder, Core and Master database connection strings and select the Sitecore version installed on your instance (only 7.2) and follow the next steps. If you need more info, you must read the Guide that comes in the url provided ("Express-migration-tool-1.0-guide").